# Objective-C, Core-Data issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsarray

I use **Core-Data** in my Iphone application. In my **Core-Data** I have something like that;

[object:table, number:2]

[object:table, number:4]

[object:window, number:2]

[object:window, number:5]

[object:chair, number:2]

[object:chair, number:3]

How can I get a NSArray with table's lowest number, window's lowest number and chair's lowest number? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

taken STRAIGHT from the apple website

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html

1) specify the type of entity you want to get

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
    entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
```

2) specify the charateristics you are looking for, (you can ignore this since you want all)

```
// Set example predicate and sort orderings...
NSNumber *minimumSalary = ...;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"(lastName LIKE[c] 'Worsley') AND (salary > %@)", minimumSalary];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

3) specify the order

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
    initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

NSError *error;
NSArray *array = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (array == nil)
{
    // Deal with error...
}
```

4) you get a sorted array so... either get the last or first entry, depending on the ordering you pick.

Comment: if table, window and chair are different entities then you fetch for each of them in the same way as above, if they are the same entity you can fetch 3 times using the predicate to search for something like @"type = chair" then the rest of the answer is the same, OR you can sort it just like above and inside the array to a simple for loop in the array searching for any of the 3 when you find the first of the 3, you have the lowest for that one, then you keep going trough the array till you get the other 2 first objects of such types.